# Emacs Speaks Statistics: auto-close curly brackets

Tags: emacs, ess

I am using the very nice modified version of Emacs, by Vincent Goulet, with `ess` included, dowloaded from [here](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/) .

In my `.emacs` file I set the `skeleton-pair` option like this

```
(setq skeleton-pair t)
(global-set-key (kbd "(") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "[") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "{") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "\"") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "\'") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "\`") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
```

This works for all types of files apart from R-scripts where the auto-closing for curly brackets `{}` does not work (the rest works fine).

In the past, when I used to download the `ess` directory, unzip it and define the path in my `.emacs` I used to get around this problem by commenting the following line:

```
(define-key map "{"          'ess-electric-brace)
```

in the `ess-mode.el` file at `lisp/`. Now that I am using the modified distribution, I have done the same with the `ess-mode.el` file at `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/site-lisp/ess/`, but it will not work.

Therefore, anyone knows how to automatically close curly brackets in R-scripts using the modified `Emacs`distribution with `ess`?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your `.emacs`:

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "(") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "[") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "{") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "\"") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "\'") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "\`") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
```

If that gives some errors, you may need to `(require 'ess-mode)` before the above statements.